# Request to remove a question from low quality audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I recently failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8499674) audit. It is not high quality, but does attempt to answer the question.

The problem is that I was reviewing a version of the answer that had been editted. The original version had an SEO link in it that had been edited out. A moderator then deleted the answer about fifteen minutes later.

The question, as presented to me in the queue, did not contain an inappropriate link. It was a (poor) attempt to answer the question, thus I said it looked ok.

I am requesting that it be removed as an audit because the question presented in the queue doesn't match how it appeared when it was originally flagged and why it was ultimately deleted.

Comment: The user should not have edited that answer. They should have flagged it as spam, because that's what it was, pure and blatant spam. The rest of the answer was copy-pasted from the the accepted answer above that. I've reverted the edit to make it a more clear audit.

Comment: I can't disagree with that @animuson, but the other answers aren't shown in the queue and it looked like a valid attempt at an answer which led to this request.